# What is the difference between an alias and a tag? (general and in git)

Tags: git, function, pointers, tags, alias

I am learning to use git. 
I encounter the term alias and tag. I know what they do. But It seems they both do the same thing? But then there must be a reason why they are called differently right?

So in general what is the difference between these two and how they are in git especially? Thank you!

Comment: Tag is a pointer to a commit. Aliasing is a way to create alternative commands for git. They have absolutely nothing to do with each other.

Answer (score 0):

Git [Aliases](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Git-Aliases) and [Tags](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-tag) are very different things.

Aliases provide a way of shortening git **commands**; for example, you can use `git co` instead of `git checkout`.

Tags on the other hand, provide shorthands to specific **commits**; for example, you can use them to mark a specific version of your code.

Comment: So basically alias only can shorten the commands and tags are only for commits?

Comment: @Sanctriell Basically, yes. Note that you can also tag other things like checked-in files, but most of the time you just need a tag to a commit. Aliases are also useful to have some good-looking `git log` graphs prepared so you just need to type `git graph` (or whatever your alias is called).